# How to implement RichTextFX in JavaFX project

Tags: java, javafx, rtf, richtextfx

I started to work on a JavaFX project in which I want to add a copied text without to change the format and images from my driver (it should work like open office). The images should be able to be placed within the text on different positions.
Therefore, I need a controlfield which can handle a rtf format.

For this purpose I found RichTextFX. In the documentation is explained how to run RichTextFX with Maven or Grandle. I dont use Maven or Grandle, therefore I would like to know if there is a possibility to run RichTextFX without using neither of them. I added the jar file to my project and copied the source code of RichtextFX Demo. Afer that i got many errors and it is not able to run.
Can someone maybe guide me trough this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I already figured out how to use RichtextFX.
For everyone who wants to use RichtextFX but doesn't use Gradle or Maven here is an explanation how to run RichtextFX-Demo:

1. get the fat JAR file (including dependencies)
2. integrate the JAR in your project
3. copy all classes in your project from the following link :[enter link description here](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/tree/master/richtextfx-demos/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext/demo/richtext)
4. add the pngs and the rich-text.css to your project from the following link : [enter link description here](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/tree/master/richtextfx-demos/src/main/resources/org/fxmisc/richtext/demo/richtext)

I can't answer other questions. I hope this helps to run the Demo.